# Why $_ =~ "regular expression" is valid in Perl?

Tags: perl

I know in Perl, a most common valid regular expression is like this:

```
$_ =~ m/regular expression/;

# and "m" can be omit
$_ =~ /regular expression/;
```

And I can use `qr` to create a regular expression reference like this:

```
my $regex = qr/regular expression/;
$_ =~ m/$regex/;

# and "m//" can be omit:
$_ =~ $regex;
```

But I have tried this:

```
my $str = "regular expression";
$_ =~ $str; # why this is valid?
```

It didn't give me any error infomation and worked fine. I don't know why, I think it should be like:

```
my $str = "regular expression";
$_ =~ m/$str/;

# or
my $str = "regular expression";
my $regex = qr/$str/;
$_ =~ $regex;
```

Can anyone explain why `$_ =~ $str` is valid in Perl?

Comment: Does It mean there is an implicit convert from `string` to `qr//` when I use `$_ =~ $str` ?

Comment: @Lane  See my completed answer. Any expression can be used as a pattern when fed to the `=~` operator.

Comment: They are the same thing. One is the customary form while the other is the generic form. They are converted to the same construct.

Comment: @Rafael  "_They are the same thing._" -- no, they are not.  For _some patterns_ either can be used but for a range of needs that doesn't hold (`qr` can do far more).  I believe that you merely misspoke (assuming one of those patterns for which both work the same) but I am commenting as a clarification for those who aren't well versed in regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It says under ["The basics" in perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

> Patterns that aren't already stored in some variable must be delimitted, at both ends, by delimitter characters.

( along with the incorrect double-t in delimite(d/r) ) And there is a bit more liberty than what this seems to allow, as patterns in a string don't need delimiters either. See below.

Thus, a pattern in a variable just doesn't need delimiters.  The operator `=~` discussed in ["Binding operators" in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators)

> binds a scalar expression to a pattern match.

and (with my emphasis)

> If the right argument is an expression rather than a search pattern, substitution, or transliteration, it is **interpreted as a search pattern at run time.**

The operator doesn't care for delimiters on its right hand side and a "regex pattern" can be formed at runtime out of an expression.

The section ["Gory details of parsing quoted constructs" in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Gory-details-of-parsing-quoted-constructs) helps with this as well, apart from being illuminating in its own right. After the quoted construct is identified and the contained text interpolated it comes to the bullet "parsing regular expressions"

> After preprocessing described above ... the resulting **string** is passed to the RE engine for compilation.

(my emphasis)

This is a general discussion of how Perl handles quoted constructs and
there is no requirement for (extra) delimiters once the string is formed out of the quoted construct.  The `m/RE/` (etc) are discussed earlier in the  "*interpolation*" bullet, what shows some of the things that can't be used with a plain string for a pattern, but that is clearly not compulsory to have.

An example

```
"hello" =~ ( '(' . join('|', qw(a b l)) . ')' );  # now $1 has "l"
```

The outer parenthesis on the RHS are there for precedence only, to isolate the expression yielding a pattern.  One can use a `do` block, as well: `$s =~ do { ... };`

I'd recommend against this though; use `qr`, as you expect.  For one thing, using a string (and not a regex built with `qr`) is limiting. Also, it is more prone to silly errors.

---

Note that while for many patterns one can use either `qr` or `""` (or its operator form `qq()`) to prepare the pattern (or the string which will be interpreted that way) -- they are not the same. Their quoting rules are quite similar but the `qr` prepares a *regular expression* which, as put in [Regexp Quote-Like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)

> ... magically differs from a string containing the same characters ...

For one, recall that with `qr` you may use modifiers.

Comment: `For one thing, using a string (and not a regex built with qr) is limiting. Also, it is more prone to silly errors.` => If I use `""`(double quotation marks) string, it may lead some escape problems. But if I use `''`(single quotation marks) string, `'expression'` and `qr/expression/` are almost the same, am I right?

Comment: @Lane Not quite. For one, `qr//` interpolates `$variables`. It also detects errors earlier: `qr/)/` is a hard error.

Comment: @Lane  Added a note at the end, I hope that it helps.  The single quotes `''` don't interpolate so they are different. The `""` (double quotes) do and they are most similar to `qr`. The escape issues indeed exist as the main (only?) difference in quoting rules for them.  However, there are other differences and I recommend to use `qr` for a regex.

Comment: @melpomene @zdim Thank you. I think I got the point, they are close but they are different. In most common cases `''` and `""` may work fine but I'd better use `qr//`.

Answer (score 3):

Perl strives to be a natural language, as such, these customary forms, `''` and `""`, may have different generic forms depending on the context. Here is the table taken straight out of [Programming Perl, 4th Edition (pg. 71)](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do), Table 2-7. Quote constructs:

> ```
> +-----------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+
> | Customary | Generic | Meaning               | Interpolates |
> +-----------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+
> | ''        | q//     | Literal string        | No           |
> +-----------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+
> | ""        | qq//    | Literal string        | Yes          |
> +-----------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+
> | ``        | qx//    | Command execution     | Yes          |
> +-----------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+
> | ()        | qw//    | Word list             | No           |
> +-----------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+
> | //        | m//     | Pattern match         | Yes          |
> +-----------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+
> | s///      | s///    | Pattern substitution  | Yes          |
> +-----------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+
> | tr///     | y///    | Character translation | No           |
> +-----------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+
> | ""        | qr//    | Regular expression    | Yes          |
> +-----------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+
> ```

**Example:**

The string is converted to a pattern in this example. You have to take care here though, for when you construct patterns from double-quoted strings, you must escape the slash.

You can clearly see here:

```
my $pat = "hello\\s+world"; #double-slash to escape the slash

if ("hello       world" =~ $pat) {
    print "hello, world\n";
}
```

output:

```
hello, world
```

Comment: If I use `''`(single quotation marks) string, I don't need "double-slash to escape the slash", it's the same as `qr` sytle pattern, right?

Comment: You are half correct, `&#39;&#39;` is customary for `q//`, not `qr//`, no slash is required because it is not interpolated, the string is processed "as-is."

Comment: Would you mind adding the page and edition for your quote please?

Comment: This is misleading. (Is it in a specific context in the good book?)  While `''` and `q()` can stand for each other, `""` and `qr//` aren't the same thing (even as we may use either _for some patterns_).

Comment: @zdim yes, they are context specific. Look at row 2 and the last row.

Comment: Sure -- what I mean is that "_customary_" and "_generic_" may easily be misunderstood to say that they can be used interchangeably, specially with all other examples being that way.  I'm thinking that when the table is taken out of the book (so to speak) in this way then the last line stands out as a sore thumb in that sense -- all others are practically intechangeable while the last one patently isn'.t

Comment: @Lane, @zdim, No, `'\\s'` (matches a whitespace) is not the same thing as `qr/\\s/` (matches `\ ` followed by `s`).

Comment: @zdim, In a way, `""` and `qr//` are quite close, as both are interpolating (including `\u`, `\Q` and such). The difference is that `qr//` passes through escapes still escaped.

Comment: @ikegami What I meant to point out (here and elsewhere in comments on this page) is that they are not the _same_.  Apart from a small difference in how quoting works the `qr` also takes modifiers. (I think that there are yet other things that `qq()` can't do for regex while `qr` can but I can't recall them.)

Comment: @zdim, `qq` has more character escapes (e.g. `\b` produces backspace or something), but that's it

Answer (score 2):

This is answered by the documentation for `=~` in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> If the right argument is an expression rather than a search pattern, substitution, or transliteration, it is interpreted as a search pattern at run time.

---

There are only a few things that can legitimately follow `=~`:

- A match operator (`m//`)
- A substitution operator (`s///` )
- A transliteration operator (`tr///`)

Now, Perl *could* give a syntax error as you expect if anything else if found on the right-hand side of `=~`. But it does something far more useful instead. If it finds something other than the above operators, the result of the expression is used as the pattern for an implicit match operator.

This conveniently allows

```
$s =~ get_pattern()               # do { my $pat = get_pattern(); $s =~ /$pat/ }
```

and

```
$s =~ ( $sub_pat1 . $sub_pat2 )   # do { my $pat = $sub_pat1 . $sub_pat2; $s =~ /$pat/ }
```